# The requested URL not found - in Digital Ocean LAMP Webmin server

Tags: 16.04, php, virtualhost, webmin, mod-rewrite

I'm new to Digital Ocean & Ubuntu, in the midst of migrating from [Exabyte](https://www.exabytes.com/) shared server's [Codeigniter *(v3)*](https://codeigniter.com/) website to Digital Ocean server

**Server details/installation :**

```
Digital Ocean Droplet - Ubuntu LAMP on 16.04
Apache - Apache/2.4.18 ( Ubuntu )
PHP - PHP 5.6.30-10+deb.sury.org~xenial+2 (cli) 
Webmin - version 1.831
```

**Codeigniter setup**

Codeigniter website is already configure on [removing index.php from url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19183311/codeigniter-removing-index-php-from-url) and it's working fine on shared server, but not working fine on Digital Ocean's server...

**Problem on mod_rewrite**

When I uploaded all my codeigniter files to Digital Ocean, then I browse **sample.com**, it's working fine.

but when I browse **sample.com/about** it will prompt me `The requested URL /about was not found on this server.`

but when i do browse **sample.com/index.php/about** it works fine.

I'd try modify **apache2.conf** at webmin > servers > apache webserver > global configuration > edit config files :

```
<Directory /var/www/>
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    Require all granted
</Directory>
```

Whether I modify `AllowOverride None` to `AllowOverride All` ( i did reset apache ) the site still not working good...

**Webmin > Servers > Apache Webserver > Virtualhost:**
[image]

**allow mod_rewrite via ssh command:**

```
a2enmod rewrite
sudo service apache2 restart
```

May I know how do I modify the ubuntu server and able to browse my codeigniter framework normally with **sample.com/about**

Did I setup virtualhost wrongly using *Webmin*'s method?

Do I need to install any third party module to make it work?
 or enable any configure in Digital Ocean?

thanks alot!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Once I added a virtual host via webmin,

I will need modify **sites-available** .conf and add these codes to wrap inside my domain's `<Directory>` :

```
Options FollowSymLinks MultiViews
AllowOverride All
Order allow,deny
Allow from all
```

[image]